mui datepicker forward ref function to open
this is my code :
  <Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    <DatePicker ref={DateRef} sx={{display:'none'}}/>
                </LocalizationProvider>
                <Box sx={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Typography variant='h5' fontWeight={'bold'}>
                    Calender
                </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box display={'flex'} gap={2}>
                    <IconButton onClick={()=>DateRef.current.openCalendar()} sx={{backgroundColor:'#D9D9D9',color:'black'}}>
  
                        <CalendarMonth/>
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton sx={{backgroundColor:'#D9D9D9',color:'black'}}>
                        <Close/>
                    </IconButton>
                </Box>
            </Box>

i just want to open the datepicker whenever click on the calenderMonth icon.In this part<IconButton onClick={()=>DateRef.current.openCalendar()}, actually 'current.openCalendar' is not really the function to open. so i appreciate the correct answer from your side guys.....

The event which opens DatePicker pop up is on InputAdornment's IconButton. So, you'll need to fire click event on the IconButton from Calender Month button.
Use
<Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DatePicker
                sx={{display: 'block'}}
                slots={{
                    openPickerIcon: ()=><Event ref={DateRef}/>
                }}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
        <Box sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Typography variant='h5' fontWeight={'bold'}>
                Calender
            </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box display={'flex'} gap={2}>
            <IconButton onClick={() => DateRef.current?.parentElement.click()} sx={{backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9', color: 'black'}}>
                <CalendarMonth/>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton sx={{backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9', color: 'black'}}>
                <Close/>
            </IconButton>
        </Box>
    </Box>


can you create a sandbox replicating your issue
